# Scanf() - What is the %a format/conversion specifier?

Tags: c, floating-point, formatting, scanf, format-specifiers

In C there is the opportunity to implement `%a` as format specifier inside a `scanf()` format string for the formatting of floating point values.

Like:

```
float v;
scanf("%a",&v);
```

In the C Standard (My relation is especially ISO/IEC 9899/2011 (C11)) is only less explained about that certain specifier and nothing to its difference to the associated floating-point conversion specifiers of `%f`,`%e` and `%g` :

Citation, ISO/IEC 9899/2011, §7.21.6.2:

> a,e,f,g - Matches an optionally signed ﬂoating-point number, inﬁnity, or NaN, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtod function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to ﬂoating.

What does this specifier and what is its intended use? 
Where is the particular difference to the other floating-point conversion specifiers?

Comment: It's a C99-introduced specifier and (possibly?) allows for hex-format floating-point input: [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Comment: @AdrianMole "It (`"%a"`) allows for hex-format floating-point input:" is bit amiss.  _hex-format floating-point input_ is allowed by C99, but it works for `%a, %A, %e, %E, %f, %F, %g, %G, %la, %lA, %le, %lE, ... %LG`

Comment: @chux Which is why I added "(possibly?)" - the linked cppreference page says C99 allows hex input for floats, and also has the "%a" format marked as C99-specific - so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%a`, `%e`, `%f`, and `%g` format specifiers to `scanf` all perform the same conversion as noted in the quoted passage from the standard.

The Linux man page for `scanf` spells it out a bit more explicitly:

> f      Matches an optionally signed floating-point number; the next
>   pointer must be a pointer to float.
>
> e      Equivalent to f.
>
> g      Equivalent to f.
>
> E      Equivalent to f.
>
> a      (C99) Equivalent to f.

Presumably, these are present because they are also `printf` format specifiers which accept a `float` but unlike `scanf` they differ in the output they produce.

To illustrate this, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[] = { "234.56", "2.3456e2", "2.3456E2", "0x1.d51eb8p+7" };
    unsigned i;

    for (i=0; i<sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str); i++) {
        float f;

        printf("scanning %s\n", str[i]);
        sscanf(str[i], "%f", &f);
        printf("scanned with f: (f)%f, (e)%e, (g)%g, (a)%a\n", f, f, f, f);
        sscanf(str[i], "%g", &f);
        printf("scanned with g: (f)%f, (e)%e, (g)%g, (a)%a\n", f, f, f, f);
        sscanf(str[i], "%e", &f);
        printf("scanned with e: (f)%f, (e)%e, (g)%g, (a)%a\n", f, f, f, f);
        sscanf(str[i], "%a", &f);
        printf("scanned with a: (f)%f, (e)%e, (g)%g, (a)%a\n", f, f, f, f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
scanning 234.56
scanned with f: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with g: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with e: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with a: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanning 2.3456e2
scanned with f: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with g: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with e: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with a: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanning 2.3456E2
scanned with f: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with g: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with e: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with a: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanning 0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with f: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with g: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with e: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
scanned with a: (f)234.559998, (e)2.345600e+02, (g)234.56, (a)0x1.d51eb8p+7
```

Comment: But isn´t that wrong? `%e` has a different behavior than `%f`, and so the others, like `%e` isn´t also exactly the same as `%g`. None of them is straight equivalent to `%f`. This statement also would mean that `%e` is equivalent to `%E`, which isn´t quite the fact. The consensus of this citation is: all are equivalent, which is a pretty ridiculous. I can´t believe this is written in the man pages of Linux

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica — No: all the `scanf()` family floating point scanners accept any valid floating point representation, including the hexadecimal notation that `%a` and `%A` produce with the `printf()` family.  Specifying `%lf` doesn't stop you entering `6.0221409e+23` and getting an approximation to Avogadro's Number.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I know that they might accept all given floating point value representations, but there behaviors, how they exactly convert the given value, are slightly different. In case, I would go with you, and say they would behave all like the same, my question could be also formulated as: Why are so much specifiers provided by the standard, if they all do their work equivalent? And with equivalent, I mean 100% the same in their behaviors.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica See my edit for an example of the identical behavior.  As for why they're included, most likely its for symmetry with `printf`.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica — The `scanf()` functions accept multiple specifiers for floating point numbers for symmetry between `printf()` and `scanf()` formats.  For a long time (until C99 again), `scanf()` had `%lf` for reading a `double`, but `printf()` only used `%f` (because the values passed to `printf()` were always converted from `float` to `double` by the default argument promotion rules).  In C99, they added `%lf` as a synonym for `%f`, again to improve the symmetry between the two families of functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So the concept, as you say, is simply as to keep readability (or to improve it) through the code, as the `printf()` family uses the same specifiers. There is no specific reason for using them as they all will be treated like `%f`, except for the purpose of readability? But, and this might be something to ask for in a different question, the conversions behave different when used in `printf()`, despite of course `printf()`has a different purpose of operation?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica — I'm not sure whether the intention was to allow you to use `printf("%lf %d %d %lf", dbl1, int1, int2, dbl2);` to write data that could be read by `scanf("%lf %d %d %lf", &dbl1, &int1, &int2, &dbl2);` but if you use unqualified conversion specifications like that (and don't include a newline at the end of the `printf()` format string), then you could working code.  I carefully avoided `%s`; it prints data with spaces in happily, but `scanf()` stops at the first space.  As soon as you add almost any qualifier to the print format, it ceases to be usable for input.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica — and yes, the outputs from `%e`, `%f`, `%g` and `%a` are different in general, though `%g` and `%e` can be similar for numbers with large enough and small enough magnitudes.